# running python script inside shell script throws dependency error

Tags: python, python-3.x, bash, shell

I am running python script which has the below line

```
import sqlalchemy
```

If i run it in my terminal it runs fine without any issues. But if i try to execute this python script from a shell script am getting

> No module named sqlalchemy

Below is the error i get when running via shell script but running simply the above line as python script works fine.

```
Code of test_python.sh(it has only one line):
python test.py
```

Similarly, code of python script test.py(it has only one line):

```
import sqlalchemy
```

Error from shell script:

```
ARU03:~ parunkarthick$ sh test_python.sh 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 1, in <module>
    import sqlalchemy
ImportError: No module named sqlalchemy
```

I already pip installed the sqlalchemy module but when running inside from a shell script it is not able to find

Version2 output:

```
ARU32967:~ parunkarthick$ sh test_python.sh 
/usr/bin/python
['/Users/parunkarthick', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python27.zip', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/PyObjC']
/Users/parunkarthick
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 2, in <module>
    import sqlalchemy
ImportError: No module named sqlalchemy
ATH032967:~ parunkarthick$ vi test_python.sh
ATH032967:~ parunkarthick$ sh test_python.sh 
/usr/bin/python
['/Users/parunkarthick', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python36.zip', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/transforms-1.0-py3.6.egg']
/Users/parunkarthick
ATH032967:~ parunkarthick$
```

Comment: Can you provide your code for `test_python.sh`?

Comment: You should include how Python is called in `test_python.sh`,

Comment: @julienc Updated the question

Comment: @tzot updated the question

Comment: Do you have multiple python installations? When you say it runs fine from terminal, how are you getting into python from your terminal?

Comment: @busybear Yes there are multiple python installations. My python version is python --version
Python 3.6.5

Comment: I think you should use `python3 test.py` because `python` assumes python 2.x. You may install `sqlalchemy` for python2 and see if it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debugging in steps:

1. When `import sqlalchemy` succeeds, do you just run `python` and enter the import statement, or do you do `python test.py` in the command line?
2. Add the following to the top of your `test_python.sh` script:

   `which python sh`

   Also run `which python sh` in the command line. Do the outputs match?
3. Add the following to the top of your `test.py` script:

   `import sys; print(sys.path); import os; print(os.getcwd())`

   Do the same when importing sqlalchemy succeeds (see step 1).  Are the outputs the same in both occasions?
4. What other filenames exist in the current directory?

Comment: if `which` doesn't work for you, substitute `type` for it.

Comment: seems like the versions are different